# How to run a role in EC2 instance using dynamic inventory in ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I have created an ec2 instance and now when I am trying to call a role in ansible under that playbook , 
the roles runs in my local machine inspite of the ec2 instance .

```
- name: Provision an EC2 Instance
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tags: provisioning
  vars:
    secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    region: us-east-1

- hosts: localhost
  roles:
     - sdirect
```

I have used dynamic inventories. Can anyone please help or suggest something.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple example that I am using to create an ec2 instance and then run my role on it using `ec2.py` dynamic inventory:

```
- name: Provision an EC2 Instance
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tags: provisioning
  vars:
    secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    region: us-east-1
  tasks:
     - role: create-ec2-role
     - name: Refresh the ec2.py cache
       shell: ./inventory/ec2.py --refresh-cache # location of your ec2.py inventory
       changed_when: no

     - name: Refresh inventory
       meta: refresh_inventory

# Let suppose you have assign the Name "my_instance" to your Instance
- name: Run tasks on new ec2 instance
  hosts: tag_Name_my_instance
  # I assume that you have created the ubuntu ec2 instance and ssh key is in your ssh agent
  remote_user: ubuntu
  roles:
    - myrole
```

I assue that you have a directory name `inventory` in the same directory where you have playbook with the following files:

```
.
|-- ec2.ini
|-- ec2.py
`-- hosts
```

The content of the `hosts` file is simple:

```
[localhost]
127.0.0.1
```

To run the playbook, just use this command:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts yourplaybook.yml
```

Hope that might help you