# How can I run different tasks on different hosts?

Tags: ansible, splunk

I was trying to create an ansible playbook in such a way that the playbook first create an EC2 instance using host as local host

After that the instance created using above task must return IP of the new instance and on the newly created instance I wanted to install splunk can someone help me

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: create a new ec2 key pair, returns generated private key
      ec2_key:
         name: my_keypair3
         force: false
         region: us-east-1
      register: ec2_key_result

    - name: Save private key
      copy: content="{{ ec2_key_result.key.private_key }}" dest="./akey.pem" mode=0600
      when: ec2_key_result.changed

    - name: Provision a set of instances
      ec2:
         key_name: my_keypair3
         group: SplunkSecurityGroup
         instance_type: t2.micro
         image: ami-04b9e92b5572fa0d1
         wait: true
         region: us-east-1
         exact_count: 1
         count_tag:
            Name: Demo
         instance_tags:
            Name: v3

    - name: Downloading Splunk
      get_url:
         url: "https://www.splunk.com/bin/splunk/DownloadActivityServlet?architecture=x86_64&platform=linux&version=8.0.1&product=splunk&filename=splunk-8.0.1-6db836e2fb9e-linux-2.6-amd64.deb&wget=true"
         dest: ~/splunk.deb
         checksum: md5:29723caba24ca791c6d30445f5dfe6
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036488/how-to-run-a-role-in-ec2-instance-using-dynamic-inventory-in-ansible

Answer (score 0):

See [Splunkenizer](https://github.com/splunkenizer/Splunkenizer) for Ansible configuration for deploying Splunk

Comment: Link-only answers generally aren't considered valuable on SO. Please post the relevant bits here.